# How can (<$>) be left associative

Tags: haskell, associativity

I just noticed that `(<$>)` has a fixity of `infixl 4`. How can this be?

`(+1) <$> (/5) <$> [5,10]` obviously works right to left.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No, `<$>` is left associative and this is no different in your example. `(+1) <$> (/5) <$> [5,10]` is read as `((+1) <$> (/5)) <$> [5,10]`. This happens to work because of the `Functor` instance of `(->) a` is basically equivalent to function composition; `fmap (+1) (/5)` is equivalent to `\x -> (x/5)+1`, which in this instance gives you the same result as what you'd get with the order you appear to think this works in, i.e. `(+1) <$> ((+5) <$> [5,10])`.

Because this is a little bit confusing, if you want to apply multiple functions in a row it's probably better for readability to use the normal function composition operator here: `(+1) . (/5) <$> [5,10]`.

Comment: So, it does not really matter if it is left or right associative, as far as semantics is concerned (and functors indeed satisfy functor laws). I wonder if the left associaitvity was a deliberate choice, e.g. for perfomance reasons. It could even have been defined in that way by chance, or by error, in theory.

Comment: @chi If `(<$>)` were right associative, you could no longer use that `f <$> x <*> y` style pattern (because `(<*>)` would also have to be right associative, for you to use them together without parentheses like that). There are some people who say that `($)` should have been left associative, because then you could do something like `f $ g x $ h y` and it would be equivalent to `f (g x) (h y)` (and I guess it would be symmetrical with how `->` is right associative). Of course, it really comes down to preference though.